# tls unsigned certificate when using terraform

Tags: ssl, terraform, openstack, microstack

The microstack.openstack project recently enabled/required tls authentication as outlined [here](https://opendev.org/x/microstack/commit/064aae84589c8355dd283b6ce701c35a43d67c46). I am working on deploying an openstack cluster to microstack using a terraform example [here](https://github.com/terraform-provider-openstack/terraform-provider-openstack/tree/main/examples/attach-format-mount-volume). As a result of the change, I receive an unknown signed cert error when trying to create an openstack network client data source.

```
data "openstack_networking_network_v2" "terraform" {
name = "${var.pool}"
}
```

The error I get when calling `terraform plan`:

```
Error: Error creating OpenStack networking client: Post "https://XXX.XXX.XXX.132:5000/v3/auth/tokens": OpenStack connection error, retries exhausted. Aborting. Last error was: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
with data.openstack_networking_network_v2.terraform,
on datasources.tf line 1, in data "openstack_networking_network_v2" "terraform":
1: data "openstack_networking_network_v2" "terraform" {
```

Is there a way to ignore the certificate error, so that I can successfully use terraform to create the openstack cluster?  I have tried updating the generate-self-signed parameter, but I haven't seen any change in behavior:

```
sudo snap set microstack config.tls.generate-self-signed=false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I did not source the admin-openrc.sh file that I had downloaded from the horizon web page:

```
$ source admin-openrc.sh
```

Answer (score 4):

I think [`insecure` provider parameter](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/terraform-provider-openstack/openstack/latest/docs#insecure) is what you are looking for:

> (Optional) Trust self-signed SSL certificates. If omitted, the OS_INSECURE environment variable is used.

Try:

```
provider "openstack" {
  insecure = true
}
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tried that.

Comment: This is really helpful. Was facing this issue and setting insecure flag helped.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, if it could help, here my contribution :

`sudo snap get microstack config.tls`

```
Key                              Value
```

`config.tls.cacert-path           /var/snap/microstack/common/etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem`
`config.tls.cert-path             /var/snap/microstack/common/etc/ssl/certs/cert.pem`
`config.tls.compute               {...}`
`config.tls.generate-self-signed  true`
`config.tls.key-path              /var/snap/microstack/common/etc/ssl/private/key.pem`

In terraform directory, do :

`cat /var/snap/microstack/common/etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem` : copy paste -> cacert.pem

`cat /var/snap/microstack/common/etc/ssl/certs/cert.pem` : copy/paste -> cert.pem

`cat /var/snap/microstack/common/etc/ssl/private/key.pem` : copy/past -> key.pem

And create a file in your terraform directory main.tf :

```
provider "openstack" {
  user_name   = "admin"
  tenant_name = "admin"
  password    = "pass" (get with sudo snap get microstack config.credentials.keystone-password)
  auth_url    = "https://host_ip:5000/v3"
  #insecure = true (uncomment & comment cacert_file + key line)
  cacert_file = "/terraform_dir/cacert.pem"
  #cert = "/terraform_dir/cert.pem" (if needed)
  key = "/terraform_dir/private.pem"
  region      = "microstack" (or regionOne)
```

}

To finish terraform plan/apply